# Old B&D Miter Saw rehab - Blade Guard

Tags: repair, saw, miter

I've inherited an old Black & Decker miter saw that works great but is missing it's blade guard.

I've tried finding a replacement part specifically for this model (3091/1) but can't locate the model anywhere. Seems to pivot off of a central nut... though also has two knobs on the front end that seem to have something to do with a guard(?)

Any suggestions on how I go about getting a blade guard that will fit this?  *More info in photos attached.*

[image: Full saw - side view]

[image: Model plate info]

[image: More plate info]
[image: Front view]
[image: Top view]

Comment: Are you sure that 3091/1 is the model #?

Comment: Maybe B+D will send you parts. https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/1988/black-decker-recalls-miter-saws-made-since-82  (Mostly joking, but there is a phone number there... you might get lucky.)

Comment: yeah it looks like that model is subject to a recall about a guard problem,  you might get it fixed for free.

Comment: I think the red knob is the spindle lock for changing the blade.